# Discord.py No such file or directory even though it does exist

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using a script to load my bots tokens from a file and it was working earlier in the year, I recently switched to a PC from a Laptop and transferred all my files over and now I'm getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meeracoat\Documents\!Discord\Discord Bots\Bacon Butler\launcher.py", line 5, in <module>
    bot.run(VERSION)
  File "C:\Users\Meeracoat\Documents\!Discord\Discord Bots\Bacon Butler\lib\bot\__init__.py", line 88, in run
    with open("./lib/bot/token.0", "r", encoding="utf-8") as tf:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './lib/bot/token.0'
```

This is the code.

```
def run(self, version):
        self.VERSION = version

        print("running setup...")
        self.setup()

        with open("./lib/bot/token.0", "r", encoding="utf-8") as tf:
            self.TOKEN = tf.read()

        print("running bot...")
        super().run(self.TOKEN, reconnect=True)
```

As you can see, the file exists in the given directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing the correct path, the file is not named `token.0`, it's called `token.0.txt`

```py
with open("./lib/bot/token.0.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as tf:
    self.TOKEN = tf.read()
```

Comment: Thank you for this, no clue why it suddenly needed this now when it didnt before. Now to go fix my other errors haha.